# Are there any throttlebodies known to fit as replacement for SU carbs?

Tags: carburetor, throttle-body

I'm planning to build injection in an engine that originally uses two SU HS6 carbs. At first i planned to use the carbs themself as throttle bodies, but they're rather worn out, and they don't have throttle position sensors on them. Considering the vast amount of different throttle bodies out there, there must be one or more throttle bodies that fit a manifold that is meant for HS6 carbs.

HS6's have four mounting holes in a square, 54mm apart from each other. The bore of the carb is 45mm, but that doesn't matter that much. The original carbs have mounts between them and the manifold. The dimensions of that mount are displayed in the picture below, you can derive the dimensions from that drawing. The three holes around the carbs are to bolt this mount to the manifold.
[image]
 Anyone who knows a throttle body that fits, or nearly fits these specs?

**EDIT:** This application is for a TR7 with 2L 4-cyl. (*Info added by Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2*)

Comment: Those are expensive carbs! I would bet your best approach would be to find a TB which is about the same bore and make an adapter plate to mount it. Just my SWAG, though.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes they are, they would need an also expensive rebuild anyway, so now is the moment to decide to go EFI or not. EFI will give a nice mpg and power boost i think, not to mention customisability. A TB with the same bore or sliightly bigger would be the best, but the most important thing for me is that it fits the manifold.

Comment: http://www.pattonmachine.com/TBI-Components.htm

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yeah I also found that guy, but his site doesn't look like it's updated recently. I doubt he still sells his stuff, but i'll contact him. It's also rather vague what you actually get when you order the kit, if it works with HS6's, how it looks and everything.

Comment: We should take this [to the Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) to discuss.

Comment: What engine is it for?  You may find that w Weber DCOE manifold is available for your engine and there is a big choice of throttle boddies that directly fit the DCOE manifold.

Comment: Google 45mm throttle body. Loads of links. http://www.ecotrons.com/components/tb/45mm-throttle-body/

Comment: @SteveMatthews It's a Triumph Slant 4 engine. (4cyl sohc) A slightly different version is also used in the Saab 99 and the Triumph Dolomite i believe. I'm also interested in manifold that may fit by the way. It would probably make for an easier EFI conversion.

Comment: @Peter Yeah the throat bore is not that of a problem, it's more the mounting hole distances. Thanks though.

Comment: If you found something close you could slot the holes or fill and re-drill them.

Comment: That could be an option, but the holes are often close to the throat so it would get rather messy.

Answer (score 1):

Which engine is this planned for? If it is the rover v8, then there is fuel injection already available from the later engines.

Comment: No, it's Triumph's own Slant 4. There's injection kits build for that also, but they include a complete manifold from the sprint engine. They're cost double their weight in gold though.